# QML TextField will not position text based on cursorPosition

Tags: qt, qml, textfield, cursor-position

I have created a simple TextField with a long text therein. Every time I run the code the LAST part of the text fields shows. Since I set cursorPosition to 1, shouldn't the FIRST part of the text field show?

```
TextField {
    x: 0
    id: inputField
    width: 100
    text: "Hello World 2! ababaabababababababa"
    color: gui.colorRGBString(GUIConstants.EColorElement_TextTitle)
    maximumLength: 128
    cursorPosition: 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the property is being evaluated before placing the text so a possible solution is to invoke it in component.OnCompleted:

```
TextField {
    id: inputField

    x: 0
    width: 100
    text: "Hello World 2! ababaabababababababa"
    color: gui.colorRGBString(GUIConstants.EColorElement_TextTitle)
    maximumLength: 128
    Component.onCompleted: inputField.cursorPosition = 1
}
```

Comment: Since this property only makes sense once the text has been set, it would seem like a pretty major oversight/bug (i.e. if you can't set this property at time of initialization).  Hoping there is some other explanation, but if not I'll try this route

Comment: @TSG Clearly it is a bug, I recommend you report it so that in the next release they can be solved